# how to go to previous article mysql id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I created a php script that I think will work but i do not know why I am getting an  Undefined index: id error for the isset($_GET['previous']) code.

this is my php code which includes the script that grabs a the specific clicked article on previous page($_GET['id']) script which creates it own unique ex.(?=2) and is working but might have something to do with it.

```
include('config.php');
$pdo = connect();

if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
$list_id = intval(($_GET['id']));
try {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM items where id ='.$list_id;
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
$list = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($list == FALSE) {

header("location: index.php");
}
}

if(isset($_GET['previous'])){
$list_id = intval(($_GET['id']));
try {
        $sql = "SELECT * from items WHERE id < '$list_id'  ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();

    }
$list = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

html:

```
?php 
    if(isset($list)) {

?>
    <div class="article-wrapper"><p class="specific-article-header"><?php echo $list['title'];?></p>
        <p><img src="<?php echo $list['photo']; ?>" class="article-images">  </p>
        <p class="article-text"><?php echo $list['description']; ?></p>
        <a href="?previous" style='color:white;'>Previus</button>
    </div>
<?php

 }
?>
```

Comment: PDO prepared statements with variables in your sql query?!, thats odd.

Comment: can you elaborate alittle more please, I am not the most knowledgeable in php ;/

Comment: Instead of having a post variable looking like `?=2`, it needs to be `?id=2`. That might be your issue

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try replace your first query with the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items where id ='$list_id'";
```